# What is the recommended file extension for GnuPG-encrypted files?

Tags: gnupg

I used `.asc` for ASCII armored (using `--armor`) encrypted messages.

But what extension should I use when encrypting `file.tar.gz` for example?

Comment: why would it matter what extension you give it?

Comment: @VipulNair It doesn’t, but I would like to use the extension that people expect for this type of file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.asc` is appropriate for all ASCII-armored output, even if the input file was in a binary format.  Traditionally the original filename will be maintained so that the recipient knows what to expect once they've decrypted the file, e.g., `file.tar.gz.asc`.

Comment: Yep, typically `.asc` for ASCII armored output & `.gpg` for binary output to be complete.

Comment: gowenfawr, do you agree with @EsaJokinen?

Comment: @sunknudsen I agree that `.gpg` or `.pgp` are the most common options for non-ASCII-armored GnuPG encrypted files, with `.bin` being a rarer but still present choice for some people.  Interestingly the choice of `.gpg` or `.pgp` may not have anything to do with whether the user is using GnuPG or PGP.  There's just less consensus for binary files than ASCII-armored files.